# Toggle datepicker calendar when clicking/touching PART_Textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

I am writing a datepicker style in xaml
The calendar popup is toggled by the calendar button next to the textbox of the datepicker
I want the calendar also toggling when clicking/touching the textbox

When adding an event trigger to the datepicker style, the calendar toggles when touching the textbox, but only shows on a mouse click and stays open, when clicking/touching the datepicker calendar button, the calendar opens and closes immediately.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.PreviewMouseDown">
<EventTrigger.Actions>
    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="myBeginStoryboard">
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsDropDownOpen">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                         Value="True" />
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

My questions:

- Is there a better way to achieve the desired behavior than using an event trigger?
- How can the calendar show and hide when touching the control while the event trigger only sets the calendar visible?
- Is it possible to assign the inverted "IsDropDownOpen" value to this property in xaml?
- or is it possible to use a conditional statement (if?) in xaml to handle both hiding and showing?

Comment: In your case, you need to decide on which event (action) to hide the calendar, may be at double click? I tried events `GotFocus` & `LostFocus`, but it did not help. Briefly answer your questions (it's my opinion): **`1`** - better, looking for someone. I think you can apply the attached behavior, but there must also be determined by action to close the calendar; **`2`** - depends on the action, closing calendar; **`3`** - no, but you can set the time after which it will be inverted, **`4`** - no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about the `EventTrigger` because it doesn't give you enough control. Instead of using that, just add a `bool IsDropDownOpen` property into your view model or code behind and bind it to the `DatePicker.IsDropDownOpen` property. This way, you are free to open and close the `Popup` anytime you want and/or in response to any single, or collection of events. For example:

```
public void TextBoxPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    IsDropDownOpen = true;
}

private void TextBoxPreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    IsDropDownOpen = true;
}

private void DatePickerSelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsDropDownOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: +1: Out of my head flew event `DataPicker.SelectionChanged`, plus your answer suitable for MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're using the wrong event. You need to drill down into the PART_TextBox event PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp in your DatePicker. Code below gives your DatePicker a name **Date**
You will need to add this logic for any other events you require.

NB This would also be more elegant if handled using MVVM practises

```
    private void PART_TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Date.IsDropDownOpen)
            Date.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        else
            Date.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Blend to make a control template, "DatePickerControlTemplate1" for the datepicker and then find x:Name="PART_TextBox". There you can EventTriggers on MouseEnter and MouseLeftButtonDown or use an InputBinding on LeftClick

```
                <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource BlueTextBoxStyle}">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ShowCalendarCommand}" />
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowCalendarCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ShowCalendarCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 </DatePickerTextBox>
```

MVVM XAML:

```
    <DatePicker IsDropDownOpen="{Binding ShowCalendar}" Template="{StaticResource DatePickerControlTemplate1}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private bool _showCalendar = false;
    public bool ShowCalendar
    {
        get
        {
            return _showCalendar;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_showCalendar != value)
            {
                _showCalendar = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ShowCalendar);
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand ShowCalendarCommand { get; private set; }

    ShowCalendarCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteShowCalendarCommand);

    private void ExecuteShowCalendarCommand()
    {
        ShowCalendar = true;
    }
```

Unfortunately, since the Calendar doesn't have focus it will close unless you set StaysOpen="true" in the DatePicker Control Template for the Popup

"PART_Popup":

```
    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="true" />
```